# VB.NET reader is closed

Tags: vb.net

I have code which allows me to send an email to a customer using customer details in my database.

```
Try
            mysqlconn.Open()
            GetEmailCredentials(credentials)
            query = "SELECT First_name, surname, email_address FROM customer,booking WHERE booking.BookingID='" & y & "' AND customer.customerID=booking.customerID"
            command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
            MsgBox("ref1")
            reader = command.ExecuteReader
            MsgBox("ref2")
            While reader.Read()
                MsgBox("ref3")
                Try
                    MsgBox(reader.GetString("email_address") & reader.GetString("First_name") & reader.GetString("surname"))
                    MsgBox("ref4")
                    Dim emailmessage As New MailMessage()
                    emailmessage.From = New MailAddress(credentials(0))
                    emailmessage.To.Add(reader.GetString("email_address"))
                    emailmessage.Subject = "EHCC Booking"
                    emailmessage.Body = "Hello " & reader.GetString("First_name") & " " & reader.GetString("surname") & Environment.NewLine & "One of your bookings has been deleted." & Environment.NewLine & "Please contact me for further details."
                    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
                    smtp.Port = 587
                    smtp.EnableSsl = True
                    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(credentials(0), credentials(1))
                    smtp.Send(emailmessage)
                    MsgBox("ref5")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    errors.Enqueue("Email details are incorrect")
                End Try
                mysqlconn.Close()
            End While
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            errors.Enqueue(ex.Message)
        Finally
            mysqlconn.Dispose()
        End Try
```

I keep on getting the error message 'Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed'.
I get all of the reference message boxes popping up, along with the one that outputs the results of the query. The query orks fine so i have no idea whats happening. I can't see anywhere where i have closed the reader, until i have closed the mysqlconnection. 
Im sorry if my explanation is clear.

Comment: Well you are closing your connection right before `End While` inside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
While reader.Read()
    ...
    mysqlconn.Close()
End While
```

To this

```
While reader.Read()
    ...
End While
mysqlconn.Close()
```